# open an activity from a fragment once the data is stored in database

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I need to open the add new tasks activity once the data is saved in the database inside a fragment. But when I call the intent function it'snot working and the app is getting  closed unfortunately. I couldn't find what the error is exactly. But once I comment the Intent function the add button is working properly. Please solve this for me.

```
package com.example.prami.prami;


public class AddNewAssignmentFragment extends Fragment{
//code elements
 View myView;
EditText txtAddAssignmentName;
Spinner ddTasksNo;
EditText txtStartDate;
EditText txtEndDate;
// DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
Button btnAddAssignmentToDB;
// Button btnGotoAddTasksPage;

SQLiteDatabase assignDB;



@Nullable
@Override



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_new_assignment, container, false);

    txtAddAssignmentName = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtAssignName);
    txtStartDate = (EditText)myView.findViewById(R.id.txtHandoverDate);
    txtEndDate = (EditText)myView.findViewById(R.id.txtSubmissionDate);
    btnAddAssignmentToDB = (Button)     myView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddAssignment);
   // btnGotoAddTasksPage = (Button)myView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddTask);

    ddTasksNo=(Spinner)myView.findViewById(R.id.spNoOfTasks);
    String taskNoArray[] = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}; //Java Array
    ArrayAdapter<String> adbTaskNo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, taskNoArray);
    adbTaskNo.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ddTasksNo.setAdapter(adbTaskNo);

    txtStartDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
            DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerDialogThemeStart();
            picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "handoverdatePicker");
        }
    });

    txtEndDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerDialogThemeEnd();
            picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "submissiondatePicker");
        }
    });

    btnAddAssignmentToDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CreateDB();
            AddAssignRecordToDB();

        }
    });

//        btnGotoAddTasksPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//            GoToAddTasksPage();
//            }
//        });



    return myView;
}

public static class DatePickerDialogThemeStart extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hyear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int hmonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int hday = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
        DatePickerDialog stdatepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,this,hday,hmonth,hyear);
        stdatepickerdialog.setTitle("Select Handover Date");
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,0);
        stdatepickerdialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

        return stdatepickerdialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int styear, int stmonth, int stday) {
        if (view.isShown()) {

            EditText txtStDate = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtHandoverDate);
            String handoverdate = String.valueOf(styear) + "/" + String.valueOf(stmonth + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(stday);

            txtStDate.setText(String.format(handoverdate,getActivity()));
        }
    }


}


public static class DatePickerDialogThemeEnd extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int subyear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int submonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int subday = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
        DatePickerDialog endatepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,this,subday,submonth,subyear);
        endatepickerdialog.setTitle("Select Submission Date");
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,0);
        endatepickerdialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

        return endatepickerdialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int endyear, int endmonth, int endday) {
        if (view.isShown()) {

            EditText txtEnDate = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtSubmissionDate);
            String submissiondate = String.valueOf(endyear) + "/" + String.valueOf(endmonth + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(endday);

            txtEnDate.setText(String.format(submissiondate,getActivity()));
        }
    }

}

public void CreateDB()
{
    assignDB = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("timeFighter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    assignDB.execSQL("Create TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myAssignInfo(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, assignName VARCHAR(50), " +
            "numOfTasks INTEGER, stDate VARCHAR(10), enDate VARCHAR(10))");
}

protected void AddAssignRecordToDB()
{

    try {

        String assignName = txtAddAssignmentName.getText().toString().trim();
        if (assignName.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"You did not enter an assignment name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        int assignTaskNo = Integer.parseInt(ddTasksNo.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
        if(ddTasksNo == null && ddTasksNo.getSelectedItem() == null ) {
           assignTaskNo = (Integer) ddTasksNo.getSelectedItem();
        }
        String assignStartDate = txtStartDate.getText().toString().trim();
        if (assignStartDate.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"You did not enter a handover date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        String assignEndDate = txtEndDate.getText().toString().trim();
        if (assignEndDate.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"You did not enter a submission date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        String query = "Insert into myAssignInfo (assignName, numOfTasks, stDate," +
                " enDate) Values('"+ assignName +"', "+ assignTaskNo +", '"+ assignStartDate +"', '"+ assignEndDate +"')";
        assignDB.execSQL(query); //executing query
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Assignment added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GoToAddTasksPage();


    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //("ex.printStackTrace")
    }

}

protected void GoToAddTasksPage()
{
    Intent goToTasks = new Intent(getActivity(), AddTasks.class);
    startActivity(goToTasks);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the entire fragment class ?

Comment: yes sure I will send it now

Comment: Also, the code to the Activity that you are trying to open

Comment: need logcat please